# What's the main difference between ReactiveCocoa and PromiseKit?

Tags: ios, promise, reactive-cocoa

ReactiveCocoa use RACSignal and PromiseKit use Promise to wrap values.
They can both chain asynchronous works together.
What's the main design difference between ReactiveCocoa and PromiseKit?

Comment: Promises: zero or one values. Signals: zero or more values.

Answer (score 6):

signals and promises are both ways to represent asynchronous operations as typed *values* that can be passed around, chained, composed, nested, etc in ways that a callback/notification/delegate cannot.

the difference between the two is like the difference between a square and a rectangle, where all promises are signals but not all signals are promises. a promise is one specific use case of a signal.

a signal represents a timeline of any number of asynchronous events, terminated by a completion or a failure. The following diagrams are all possible signals- any number of events ending in a failure or completion

```
--------------------Event(eventData)-Completion()

--------------Completion()

Event(eventData)---------Event(eventData)----------Failure(errorData)

-------------------------------------Failure(errorData)
```

a promise represents a single asynchronous event or a single asynchronous failure. the following diagrams represent possible promises:

```
-------Completion(eventData)

----------------------------------------------Completion(eventData)

--------Failure(errorData)

------------------------Failure(errorData)
```

as you can probably already see, any promise can be represented by a signal that sends Completion immediately after it sends its first Event, like so:

```
-------Event(data)+Completion()

-------------------------------------------Event(data)+Completion()

--------Failure(errorData)

------------------------Failure(errorData)
```